# schema of flatten operator in pig latin

Tags: java, apache-pig

i recently meet this problem in my work, it's about pig flatten. i use a simple example to express it

two files
===file1===
1_a
2_b
4_d

===file2  (tab seperated)===
1    a
2    b
3    c

pig script 1:

```
a = load 'file1' as (str:chararray);
b = load 'file2' as (num:int, ch:chararray);
a1 = foreach a generate flatten(STRSPLIT(str,'_',2)) as (num:int, ch:chararray);
c = join a1 by num, b by num;
dump c;   -- exception java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

pig script 2:

```
a = load 'file1' as (str:chararray);
b = load 'file2' as (num:int, ch:chararray);
a1 = foreach a generate flatten(STRSPLIT(str,'_',2)) as (num:int, ch:chararray);
a2 = foreach a1 generate (int)num as num, ch as ch;
c = join a2 by num, b by num;
dump c;   -- exception java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

pig script 3:

```
a = load 'file1' as (str:chararray);
b = load 'file2' as (num:int, ch:chararray);
a1 = foreach a generate flatten(STRSPLIT(str,'_',2));
a2 = foreach a1 generate (int)$0 as num, $1 as ch;
c = join a2 by num, b by num;
dump c;   -- right
```

i don't know why script 1,2 are  wrong and script 3 right, and i also want to know is there more concise expression to get relation c, thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you are not using PigStorage? Because it could make life so much easier for you :) .

```
a = load '/file1' USING PigStorage('_') AS (num:int, char:chararray);
b = load '/file2' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (num:int, char:chararray);
c = join a by num, b by num;
dump c;
```

Also note that, in file1 you used underscore as delimiter, but you give "-" as argument to STRSPLIT.

**edit:**
I have spent some more time on the scripts you provided; script 1 & 2 indeed does not work and the script 3 also works like this (without the extra foreach):

```
a = load 'file1' as (str:chararry);
b = load 'file2' as (num:int, ch:chararry);
a1 = foreach a generate flatten(STRSPLIT(str,'_',2));
c = join a1 by (int)($0), b by num;
dump c;
```

As for the source of the problem, i'll take a wild guess and say it might be related to this  ([as stated in Pig Documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#Schemas)) combined with pig's run cycle optimizations :

> If you FLATTEN a bag with empty inner schema, the schema for the resulting relation is null.

In your case, I believe schema of the STRSPLIT result is unknown until runtime.

**edit2:**
Ok, here is my theory explained:

[This is the complete -explain- output for script 2](http://codetidy.com/3391/) and [this is for script 3](http://codetidy.com/3392/). I'll just paste the interesting parts here.

```
|---a2: (Name: LOForEach Schema: num#288:int,ch#289:chararray)
|   |   |
|   |   (Name: LOGenerate[false,false] Schema: num#288:int,ch#289:chararray)ColumnPrune:InputUids=[288, 289]ColumnPrune:OutputUids=[288, 289]
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   (Name: Cast Type: int Uid: 288)
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |---num:(Name: Project Type: int Uid: 288 Input: 0 Column: (*))
```

Above section is for script 2; see the last line. It assumes output of `flatten(STRSPLIT)` will have a first element of type `integer` (because you provided the schema that way). But in fact `STRSPLIT` has a `null` output schema which is treated as `bytearray` fields; so output of `flatten(STRSPLIT)` is actually `(n:bytearray, c:bytearray)`. Because you provided a schema, pig tries to make a java cast (to the output of `a1`) to `num` field; which fails as `num` is in fact a java `String` represented as bytearray. Since this java-cast fails, pig does not even try to make the explicit cast in the line above.

Let's see the situation for script 3:

```
|---a2: (Name: LOForEach Schema: num#85:int,ch#87:bytearray)
|   |   |
|   |   (Name: LOGenerate[false,false] Schema: num#85:int,ch#87:bytearray)ColumnPrune:InputUids=[]ColumnPrune:OutputUids=[85, 87]
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   (Name: Cast Type: int Uid: 85)
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |---(Name: Project Type: bytearray Uid: 85 Input: 0 Column: (*))
```

See the last line, here output of `a1` is properly treated as `bytearray`, no problems here. And now look at the second to last line; pig tries (and succeeds) to make an explicit cast operation from `bytearray` to `integer`.

Comment: yes, i've used PigStorage at beginning, but the data format like '**_**' is generated in the process, so i have no choice but STRSPLIT

Comment: And the '-' is my carelessness, in practice code that's correct

Comment: thanks for you answer. but i still can't understand, when you describe **a1**, Pig gives **a1: {num: int,ch: chararray}**, why this schema can't be used in join operator. And also what the difference between script2 and script3, just one has named filed and the other not

Comment: so you mean the cast exception is happened in **AS clause**， but `dump a1` hasn't caused exception

Comment: cast exception is caused by the AS clause. though it (AS clause) is not evaluated until you call dump or store.

Comment: but i called `dump a1` and `dump a2`, both are ok. Exception only happend after join