# Exception in type casting Chararry to double in PIG

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a sample input as tab separated key, value pair as follows

```
B_1001@2012-06-15   96.73429163933419@0.5511284347710459
B_1001@2012-06-18   187.4348199976547@0.5544551559243536
B_1002@2012-09-26   745.4912066349087@0.8398570478932768
B_1002@2012-09-28   60.97117969729124@0.8500267379723409
```

and I am loading this file into pig and doing the following

```
a = load '/home/HadoopUser/Desktop/a.txt' as (key:chararray, value:chararray);

describe a;
a: {key: chararray,value: chararray}

b = foreach a generate key, flatten(STRSPLIT(value,'@',2)) as (v1:double,v2:float);
describe b;
b: {key: chararray,v1: double,v2: float}

c = group b by key;
 describe c;
c: {group: chararray,b: {key: chararray,v1: double,v2: float}}
```

this works till here
but
when I use Arthematical calculations over b.v1 I am getting ClassCastException as java.lang.String can't be casted to java.lang.Double

but describe gives no error

```
d = foreach c generate group,SUM(b.v1);
describe d;
d: {group: chararray,double}
```

when I dump d; it id giving the exception

I even tried typecasting  'b' as well

```
b = foreach a generate key, (tuple (double,double))STRSPLIT(value,'@',2);
```

now when I describe b;
Its giving an error as
Cannot cast tuple with schema tuple to tuple with schema tuple({double,double})

Please help me to know why is it coming like this even describe shows correct schema.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have experienced this issue before as well. I can't find the bug tracker link for it right now, but when you set the type/'cast' with a statement like `B = FOREACH A GENERATE key AS key: chararray` it will not actually cast the type (but it will change the output of `DESCRIBE`). You are right that you'll have to do an explicit cast, and [the docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#cast) say that you can cast a chararray to a double. Try something like:

```
b1 = FOREACH b GENERATE key, (double)v1, (float)v2 ;
```

**Update:** Here is the link to the bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2315

Comment: Thanks a lot the above thing worked exactly.
this link explained me why as well
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213659/schema-of-flatten-operator-in-pig-latin 
PIG Schema.
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#Schemas